# What does "matter of general" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> The [Rapoport's Rules](https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Rapoport%27s_Rules) are a set of rules intended to encourage productive, critical discourse. In particular, the rules seek to avoid straw man representations of an opponent's argument (similar to the ""steel man" concept[1]) and to avoid the backfire effect that criticism often provokes. The rules are most commonly seen in Daniel Dennett's reformulation:
>
> 1. You should attempt to re-express your target's position so clearly, vividly, and fairly that your target says, "Thanks, I wish I’d thought of putting it that way."
> 2. You should list any points of agreement (especially if they are not **matters of general** or widespread agreement).
> 3. You should mention anything you have learned from your target.
> 4. Only then are you permitted to say so much **as a word of rebuttal or criticism**.

What does "matter of general" mean? Also, what are the differences between "as a word of rebuttal or criticism" and a simple "rebuttal or criticism"? I search for them but there is no useful explanation.

Comment: They're not matters of general agreement. Nor are they matters of widespread agreement.

Comment: It means "if they are not matters of **general agreement** or if they are not matters of **widespread agreement**".

Comment: 4. Only then are you permitted to say **anything at all**. In both cases, you have mistaken the phrasing. in (4) it is *so much as*, meaning "*even* a word of..."

Answer (score 1):

The string "matters of general" isn't a coherent phrase.   The coordination "general or widespread" applies as a unit to "agreement".   The nearly synonymous alternatives are "matters of general agreement" and "matters of widespread agreement".

> 4. Only the are you permitted to *make even the **smallest beginning*** of any rebuttal or criticism.